Given x and y are real number such that $x^2+y^2=1$. Find the minimum and maximum value of $s=\frac{(x+y)^2-3y^2}{xy+1}$
Given x and y are real number such that $x^2+y^2=1$. Find the minimum and maximum value of $$s=\frac{(x+y)^2-3y^2}{xy+1}$$
I tried to convert $\frac{(x+y)^2-3y^2}{xy+1}$ into terms of xy but can’t seem to do so, is there anyway to convert? or a way to do the problem in general.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Just set $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial s}{\partial y} = 0$

@Amogh is there any way to do without partial derivatives or derivatives?

Use a trigonometric substitution, but then be aware that it gets hairy afterwards.  The max/min occurs at $ \theta = \tan^{-1} ( 3 \pm \sqrt{13}) $, hence the warning.

First, make everything homogeneous by substituting $1=x^2 + y^2$ in the denominator:
$$s=\frac{(x+y)^2 - 3y^2}{xy+x^2+y^2}$$
Note that if $y=0$, then $s=1$.  We can file this for later and handle the case of $y\ne0$ and $s\ne1$.
Substitute $t=\frac{x}{y}$.  Any value of $t$ can be achieved by some combination of $x$ and $y$ subject to $x^2+y^2=1$.  So we can restate the question as "Which values of $s$ allow $s=\frac{(t+1)^2-3}{t^2+t+1}$ to be solved for $t$?".
Since $t^2+t+1$ cannot be zero, the equation can be rearranged as a quadratic for $t$:
$$(s-1)t^2 + (s-2) t + (s+2) = 0$$
This will have a solution for $t$ iff the discriminant is not negative:
$$(s-2)^2 - 4(s-1)(s+2)\ge0$$
$$\frac{-4-2\sqrt{13}}{3} \le s \le \frac{-4+2\sqrt{13}}{3}$$
Since $s=1$ is included in the above interval, we don't need to handle it separately and the inequality gives the full range of $s$.

$$s=\frac{(x+y)^2-3y^2}{xy+1}$$
Divide numerator and denominator by $x^2$
$$s=\frac{\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^2-3\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}{\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
The condition $x^2+y^2=1$ implies $\frac{1}{x^2} = 1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2$
$$s=\frac{\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^2-3\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}{\frac{y}{x}+1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}$$
Parametrizing $x=\sin\theta$ and $y=\cos\theta$, we get $\frac{y}{x}=\tan\theta=t \in (-\infty, \infty)$
$$s=\frac{\left(1+t\right)^2-3t^2}{t+1+t^2}$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $t$ and setting $\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}=0$ will give you the critical points

This was tagged precalculus, so maybe one is expected just to graph it or maybe it is mistagged.

The answer done by Mathematica 14.1 is not of a simple form.
Maximize[{((x + y)^2 - 3 y^2)/(x*y + 1), x^2 + y^2 == 1},
 {x,  y}] // ToRadicals

$$\left\{-\frac{2}{3}
   \left(2-\sqrt{13}\right),\left\{x \to -\sqrt{\frac{2}{61} \left(19+3
   \sqrt{13}\right)},y\to
   -\sqrt{\frac{1}{61} \left(23-6
   \sqrt{13}\right)}\right\}\right\} $$
The sane with Minimize produces
$$\left\{-\frac{2}{3}
   \left(2+\sqrt{13}\right),\left\{x\to
   -\sqrt{\frac{2}{61} \left(19-3
   \sqrt{13}\right)},y\to
   -\frac{\sqrt{494-78 \sqrt{13}}+5
   \sqrt{38-6 \sqrt{13}}-2
   \sqrt{703+194 \sqrt{13}}}{6
   \sqrt{61}}\right\}\right\} $$
